# Image rollover using javascript rolling just one image

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code:

```
function roll(id,images){
    var myImage = document.getElementById(id);
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
        setTimeout(myImage.src = images[i],2000);
    }
}
function resetter(id,image){
    var myImage = document.getElementById(id);
    myImage.src = image;
}
```

to have image rollover

This is HTML:

```
        <div class="thumb">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="video_page.php?id=61" title="">
            <img src="original/12.jpg" id="videoid61" onMouseOver="roll('videoid61',['original/6.jpg','original/1.jpg','original/2.jpg','original/3.jpg','original/4.jpg']);" onMouseOut="resetter('videoid61','original/12.jpg');"/><br>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dur"></div>
</div>

        <div class="thumb">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="video_page.php?id=66" title="">
            <img src="original/111.jpg" id="videoid66" onMouseOver="roll('videoid66',['original/112.jpg','original/113.jpg','original/114.jpg','original/115.jpg','original/116.jpg']);" onMouseOut="resetter('videoid66','original/111.jpg');"/><br>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="dur"></div>
</div>
```

I have many thumbnails. I want all the images to be rotated. But this is having me rotate just one image. Is there anyway to solve this without `$()` `JQuery`? Because, I have many thumbnails, if you have any easy way to manage codes I am okay with JQuery too. But, simple javascript looks neater

Comment: `But this is having me rotate just one image.` Could you please rephrase this?

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently setting a timeout, but the syntax is incorrect. Try

```
setTimeout("myImage.src = images[i]",2000);
```

Better practice is to use a function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myImage.src = images[i];
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Rollover</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>
         <img id="img1" src="picture.jpg " alt="sample picture" height="86"
              width="44" onmouseover = "show('img1' , 'img_girl.jpg');" 
              onmouseout = "show('img1' , 'picture.jpg');" />
     </p>
    <script>
         function show(imgId , URL){
             var img = window.document.getElementById(imgId);
             img.setAttribute("src" , URL);
         }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why this should solve the OP's question. Code Only answers tend to get deleted or downvoted very rapidly..